# Installing linux and need to change boot menu option to very specific settings

Tags: system-installation, reboot

Installing linux and need to change boot menu option to very specific settings.
I'm also new to linux and need alot of help.

Comment: This question could use more detail if you want a detailed answer. Please [edit] your question to include the very specific settings you require (and why you need them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch a terminal, and enter the following commands in order:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

This will install Grub Customizer, a GUI program that allows you to configure Grub to very specific settings.